# (CSS) List elements: floating left but append to each other without spacing bottom?

Tags: css, list

do anyone have a solution for that problem I have?
It would be nice that the list-elements should append to each other without space from the bottom of each element. Actually by new row the height of the row its the height of the largest element.. I hope you know what I mean.
Sorry for my bad english!

See the Image for better understanding.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a css-only answer, and it really depend on where you want to the gap. here is what you can do with jQuery.

```
var heightest = 0;

$('li').each(function() {
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    if(thisHeight > heightest){
        heightest = thisHeight
    }
})

// got the heightest height. 

$('li').height(heightest);
```

Comment: I don't need the highest element to know. What I need is the element ordered like this: http://prntscr.com/6fl5bx

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with javascript to get height of elements to work on it, but first of all you should create some columns and then put boxes into cols...

Comment: what i mean from cols is dividing your container to some smaller containers that are standing aside each other ,  and then put the items into smaller containers...

Comment: For some that have similiar issue: there is what i need: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout